# Why is the array in a returned struct in C not freed?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;
} person_t;

person_t
read_person(void);

int main(){
    person_t Peter = read_person();
    printf("%s %d\n", Peter.name, Peter.age);
}

person_t
read_person(void) {
    person_t a;
    a.name = "Peter";
    a.age = 18;
    return a;
}
```

So, in the function read_person, a struct person_t is returned. I wonder if the array a.name will be freed when the function finishes, since "a" is a local variable.

It turns out that the following line is printed when the programme runs

```
Peter 18
```

which means a.name is not freed. Can someone provide an explanation to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `a` from `read_person` it will make a copy of the contents. The storage for the local variable `a` will indeed be removed once the program leaves `read_person` since it us an automatic variable.

`name` is a pointer and it will be pointing to a string literal `"Peter"` which has static storage duration this means it will last the life of the program and pointer does not need to be `free`ed. Note that attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behavior so you can not modify the contents of `name`.

If on the other hand `name` was pointing to `malloc`ed memory then it would need to be `free`ed. Alternatively it you declared a local variable in `read_person` such as this:

```
 char arr[] = "Peter" ;
```

and you assigned `a` to that then you would have undefined behavior since `arr` would no longer exist once you leave `read_person`.

Comment: I don't think this question is about the literal "Peter", but about the value held in `a.name`, which could just as easily be a dynamically allocated value.

Comment: @shafik, I've tried to change the code to `a.name = malloc(100);
strcpy(a.name, "Peter");`. Apparently, it still works. Why is that? But by declaring `arr[]` and later assigning `a.name` to it, nothing is printed out.

Comment: @user2362322 In the first case you are dynamically allocating memory which you assign to the pointer `name`. Dynamically allocated memory will exist until you subsequently `free` it. In the next case `arr` is a local(automatic) variable and will cease to exist when you exit the function and so `name` will point to memory that is not valid and we can not really predict the contents of.

Answer (score 1):

First, `name` not an array, it's a pointer to `char`, to be precise, points to a string literal `"Peter"`. And string literals have static storage, it's OK to access them anytime.

Second, it's true that `a` is a local variable, but you are returning the `struct`, not a pointer, so the value of `a` is assigned to the variable `Peter`, it's fine to access it in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if the array a.name will be freed when the function finishes, since "a" is a local variable.

`read_person` is not returning a reference to a local variable. Instead it is returning a copy. So, the program has defined behavior.

And `"Peter"` is string literal which has static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we are on a 32bit machine, so pointers and ints are both 4 bytes.  Then the size of your structure is 8 bytes (it could be more but I'm simplifying).

At compile time, a place is set aside in static memory with enough space to hold 6 characters, `'P', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r'`, and a null zero.  The location of the `'P'` will be some address like A1.  This data is located in *static memory*.

At run time:
First `main()` gets put on the *stack memory*.
Then 8 bytes are reserved on the stack, this is the variable named peter.
Then `read_person()`is put onto the stack.
Then another 8 bytes are put onto the stack; this is the variable named `a`.
Then the value A1 is put into the first 4 bytes of `a`.
Then the value 18 is put into the second 4 bytes of `a`.
Then the function returns.  Upon returning:  The entire 8 bytes from the stack at `a` is copied into the stack at `peter`.  Then `read_person` is taken off the stack.
So now the first 4 bytes of peter contain the value A1.  The second 4 bytes contain 18.
Then the `printf` statement is put onto the stack where `read_person` was.  The 4 byte value A1 and the 4 byte value 18 are also put onto the stack for `printf` to use.
The print statement does it's thing and is taken back off the stack, as are the parameters it was given.
Main is now done, it is taken off the stack, the stack is now empty again.

Notice how nothing was ever allocated from the *heap memory*.  At no point did the program ask the operating system to give us space from the heap to work with using a `malloc` or similar call.  Therefore, there is nothing to free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. I think what you are missing here is the implicit copy operation invoked by returning from the function. It is true that `person_t a` lives on the stack frame of `read_person()`. However, when you `return a`, the values in `a` are copied member-wise into the `person_t Peter` that lives in `main()`s stack frame, because of the assignment (`Peter = read_person()`). After the copy is done, the `person_t a` object in `read_person()`s stack frame is indeed freed (but not recursively - it does not do the equivalent of `free(a.name)`, which I think is what you were concerned about).

Depending on your optimization settings, and the age of your compiler, it might be even more complex, with `a` being copied into a temporary unnamed `person_t`, which is then copied into `Peter`. However, many compilers can easily optimize out the extra copy.

In fact, it could even be simpler than that, as well - if that is the entirety of your program, the compiler could recognize that that's the only call of `read_person()`, and choose to `inline` the function into `main()`, after which further optimizations might notice that `a` and `Peter` can be collapsed into one object, in which case `read_person()` would effectively be constructing `Peter` in place, and there would never even be an `a`...

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking about is variable scope. You are correct in that `a` is declared and initialized in the scope of `read_person`, however by returning it back to a variable in the main function you have now brought it into `main()` scope. It will go out of scope when main exits.